# Taylor Series Expansion to Find Value of Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How to use Taylor series of $xe^x$ to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+2)n!}=1$?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you actually written down the Maclaurin series of $xe^x$?

Comment: I dont see why I need to use the Taylor expansion

Comment: Why isnt radius of conversion enough to proves that the series converges to 1?

Comment: The radius of convergence is infinity? How does this prove anything about the value of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series expansion of $xe^x$ is
$$xe^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+2}}{k!(k+2)}=xe^x-e^x+C$$
When $x=0$ the LHS sum is clearly $0$ hence we can find $C$
$$x=0\implies0=0-1+C\implies C=1$$
$$\therefore\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+2}}{k!(k+2)}=xe^x-e^x+1$$
Then plugging $x=1$ into both sides of the equation gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!(k+2)}=1\cdot e^1-e^1+1=1$$